# google directory api java - Invalid Password

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-directory-api, google-provisioning-api

I'm trying to create a new user account via the Google Directory API using the code below. The result I get back is invalid password. What password? Problem with the P12 file I downloaded?

```
Collection<String> SCOPE = Arrays.asList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user");
String serviceAcctEmailAddress = "xxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com";
String serviceAcctUser = "admin@x.com";

    final HttpTransport TRANSPORT = new NetHttpTransport();
    final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = new JacksonFactory();

    GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
        .setTransport(TRANSPORT)
        .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
        .setServiceAccountId(serviceAcctEmailAddress)
        .setServiceAccountUser(serviceAcctUser)         
        .setServiceAccountScopes(SCOPE)
        .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File("1fc6.p12"))
        .build();

    Directory directory = new Directory.Builder(TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
        .setApplicationName("API-Project")
        .build();

    // create user object
    User u = new User();
    UserName un = new UserName();  
    un.setGivenName(".");
    un.setFamilyName("x@x.com");
    u.setName(un);
    u.setPassword("Axxx1234");
    u.setHashFunction("SHA-1");
    u.setPrimaryEmail("x@x.com");
    u.setSuspended(false);
    u.setAgreedToTerms(true);

    Directory.Users.Insert addUser = directory.users().insert(u);
    addUser.execute();
```

Getting the below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Invalid Password",
    "reason" : "invalid"
  } ],
  "message" : "Invalid Password"
}
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:145)
```

Thanks for any helping getting started!

Comment: Did you give the correct path to public key and private key to the field setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File("1fc6.p12")) ?? Also, are you sending the password as base 16 encoded hash value??

Answer (score 1):

Confirm the password you set for the user meets [your domain's password policy](https://support.google.com/a/answer/139399https://support.google.com/a/answer/139399?hl=en).

Answer (score 1):

It appears I was setting the hash function to SHA-1 format but I wasn't sending the password in that format. Once I removed the hash function it started working correctly.